# How to troubleshoot 2nd DNS server not applying to clients

Tags: domain-name-system

I would like to know why my secondary DNS is not showing in IPCONFIG on clients. I have made sure it is set in Scope option in DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options:

1. You're on a computer where the DNS is set manually while the IP address is set through DHCP. Check this first
2. You haven't renewed your IP address. Run ipconfig /renew
3. You've got a rogue DHCP server. Run ipconfig /all and make sure the value for DHCP server is what you expect it to be.

Comment: It only refers to DHCPv6 IAID. DHCP enabled, but doesnt list a DHCP server...for standard v4 DHCP

Comment: @Seth - Then you've got a static IP address set on that workstation. You can easily change that at command line by running 'netsh int ip reset c:\ipreset.log' or you can navigate the GUI to find it.

Comment: derr thanks Jason. I need a slice of "slow down" pie

Answer (score 0):

The second DNS server is not going to show up until the DHCP clients renew their ip address leases. Run ipconfig/release and ipconfig/renew on one of the clients and see if it picks up the second DNS server.

Comment: I am verifying this with my workstation, only one DNS server listed.

Comment: @Seth - Then it's not configured correctly.